# Huawei Ascend Y511 with Android 4.2 Jelly Bean lock screen Widgets

Tags: lock-screens, app-widgets, huawei

I cannot get the lock screen widgets to work no matter what I do. I do not have Corporate account added, just Google, Viber and Facebook. I searched the internet quite some times, but I couldn't find anything. I have the < / > icons next to the clock but when I try to slide it does not work.

The phone as said is Huawei Ascend Y511 (Bought 2 days ago, not rooted or anything) and the Android is 4.2 Jelly Bean.

Comment: Is there really no one that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it in `Settings-Security-Shortcut settings`. Try changing the icons to something different than they currently are.

If this doesn't work try a factory reset.

I have a y511 as well and I'm trying to get the unlock symbol to be at the right (3 o'clock position).